# Seemingly legal Eta reduction causing issues

Tags: haskell, pointfree

I am attempting to η-reduce the function

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> BinaryTree a -> b
foldr combiner base tree = foldMap combiner tree base where
  foldMap = ...
```

with

```
foldMap :: (a -> b -> b) -> BinaryTree a -> b -> b
```

working as intended.

I have η-reduced

```
foldr combiner base tree = foldMap combiner tree base
```

to

```
foldr combiner = flip $ foldMap combiner where
  ...
```

This works as intended. It seems like I should be able to η-reduce completely to get the pointfree function

```
foldr = flip $ foldMap where
  ...
```

However, this causes a compilation error

```
Couldn't match type ‘a -> b -> b’ with ‘BinaryTree t0’
Expected type: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> BinaryTree a -> b
  Actual type: BinaryTree t0 -> (t0 -> b -> b) -> b -> b
```

Is it possible to η-reduce farther, and if so, how?

Comment: `\combiner -> flip $ foldMap combiner` is `\combiner -> ($) flip (foldMap combiner)`, so as you can see, eta doesn't apply: the last argument on the RHS is `foldMap combiner`, not `combiner`!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error is raised, because `g b = f $ a b` is not equivalent to `g = f $ a`.

In the first case you get the following sequence of evaluation:

- apply the function `a` to `b` (call `a` with `b` as an argument)
- apply the function `f` to the result

In the second case:

- apply the function `f` to `a`

Thus, you just `flip` the `foldMap` function, but actually want to `flip` the `foldMap` function *after* passing `combiner` to it. This leads us to the conclusion, that you actually want the composition, i. e. `.` function:

```
foldr = flip . foldMap where
  ...
```

Comment: This answer is completely correct (+1), but let me add that I consider `flip . foldMap` to be less readable than the original code. Indeed, `flip . f` does not immediately trigger "oh, it's `f` with the 2nd and 3rd argument flipped", like the original code.